# Scripting exposure controls on a consumer-grade camera

Tags: camera-settings, camera-recommendation, programming

I am looking for a camera that can run a simple script of mine that will "animate" camera settings such as ISO, aperture, and focus during a longer exposure.

An application photo for this includes a car at night driving by with "pulses" of visibility and focus.

Are there any cameras that can run programs on camera settings during exposures?

Comment: Good luck with that. I'd go for multiple exposures and blend them in post.

Comment: Why would you want to change settings *during* an exposure?

Comment: @Caleb, why not?!

Comment: @Angles Because it doesn't make much sense in the context of a sensor that maps the entire exposure duration to a single image. Yes, I can see that you could make a long exposure where motion blur is something other than the usual smooth trails, but I don't see that as something that's either useful or easy for viewers to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get this working if tethering your camera to a computer (probably a laptop in a car) is an option.

I'm not sure about other makes, but Pentax has a Linux command line tethering tool which can be used to control the camera (called pktriggercord) you could script calls to this to set up the camera and take shots.

If you need to control the focus then your only option might be the sort of rigs they use for stop motion film making, these are servo driven and can spin the MF ring on your lens. The pktriggercord interface can trigger AF, but not control any manual focus operation.